# Arduino Convert int to Char

Tags: arduino

i have a value `q` that is int and can arrive only in range of 0 - 9.
and i have the sending function that needs a char value to work.
i need to convert the `q` to char value and send it.

the code im using there:

```
int q = 5;

//need to convert q to char c
//typicaly like so 'q'
//

Write(c,'!');
```

if im using something like that `c[1] = '\(q)';` i getting error from arduino app:

```
invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
```

so how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
char c;
int q = 5;

c = q + '0'; // convert the number to a character corresponding to it
```

Answer (score 0):

`Write((char)q, '!')`. Sounds like very simple question or maybe I have not understood it.